# Invoking a capistrano task on another environment

Tags: ruby, capistrano

I am trying to create tasks that sync from my production/staging environments to a local vagrant box.

I am hoping for a command like this: `cap vagrant sync_production_database` which would perform a database dump on the remote server, download it, and then import it on the vagrant box. Unfortunately, I can't find a way to execute a capistrano task on another environment.

I have my environments set up like so:

```
config
├── deploy
│   ├── production.rb
│   ├── staging.rb
│   └── vagrant.rb
└── deploy.rb
```

And here is an example of what I am trying to accomplish:

```
desc 'sync database'
task :sync_production_database do
  # executed on remote server
  # this is obviously not working
  on(:production) do |host|
    # dump database and download it
  end

  # executed on vagrant box
  on roles(:web) do |host|

  end
end
```

Comment: I did something similar in the past, but with Capistrano 2: https://github.com/arturhoo/matross/blob/master/lib/matross/mysql.rb#L92-L159

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I think it is better to use the stage parameter of the `cap` command to designate the remote stage servers rather than your local stage servers. This means your command assumes `:vagrant` as always being the local stage.

Then if `vagrant` stage servers have a role which the remote servers don't have, you can execute different tasks on each stage via the following:

```
# Assuming the following stage definitions in deploy/production.rb and deploy/vagrant.rb respectively
server 'production.example.com', roles: %w{web app}
server 'vagrant.local', roles: %w{web localhost}

# the following will execute tasks on each host
desc 'sync database'
task :sync_database do
  # executed on remote server(s)
  on roles(:app) do |host|
    # dump database and download it
  end
  # Load the servers in deploy/vagrant.rb
  invoke(:vagrant)

  # executed on vagrant box server(s)
  on roles(:localhost) do |host|
    # Create database and load dump from remote
  end
end
```

This works because `roles(...)` returns all servers loaded with the given role and since each stage has a unique role, you can retrieve only what servers you want by specifying their respective role.

Normally, without `invoke(:vagrant)`, `roles(:localhost)` in the example above wouldn't return anything since Capistrano only loads the servers defined in the given stage by default. To get around this, you can force load servers in your `vagrant` stage using `invoke(:vagrant)`. So then, `roles(:app)` returns the servers for the given stage and `roles(:localhost)` returns your vagrant servers.